# How to get the main base64 value from reader.result?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, base64

I am successful in getting the `base64` value of my file but with the value am also getting the type of file and the type of string but I don't want that. I just want the actual value as I need to send it to the backend.

**Code to convert file to base64**

```
handleUpload(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  const file = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => {
    console.log(reader.result as string);
  };
}
```

[image: base64]

I want the value starting from 'U' after the 'base64,' word.

Comment: You could use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Share your code!

Comment: @Evert updated with the code

Comment: render.result is a string, so render.result.split(';base64,')[1] is the actual base64

Comment: search for `,` character, that's the limit of a data URI header. Besides, are you sure you really need to send this data as base64? Are you 100% sure you can't rather send the 34% smaller raw binary data instead?

Comment: @Kaiido actually my backend team is taking the base64 string only and they are using it to make a download API in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a RegExp for that:

```
reader.result.replace(/^.+?;base64,/, '')
```

But as mentioned in a comment, you should also consider posting the binary as it is, without needing the conversion dance.

```
const file = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
const body = new FormData;
body.append('file', file);
fetch('/end-point', {
  method: 'POST',
  body
});
```

This way is both faster and more efficient, as base64 size is bigger than binary, and there's no need to wait for the client to convert the binary file.